# Error installing rvm on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, ruby, rails

I'm taking a web applications development course on Coursera that requires me to install Ruby and Rails. I'm following the instructions at https://class.coursera.org/webapplications-002/forum/thread?thread_id=51

When I run the command `sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`, I get the following error response:

```
       % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    988      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1383
100 20758  100 20758    0     0  35274      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 35274
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

It looks like you have old certificates, you can read more about it here:
https://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates/

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/stable.tar.gz
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

It looks like you have old certificates, you can read more about it here:
https://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates/
```

Googling for this error, it seems that this is specific to 12.04. I haven't found a solution yet. Any suggestions how to proceed? As can be gauged from the fact that I'm taking an introductory class on coursera, I'm completely new to web server applications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's just for installing Ruby and Rails, I think you can do `sudo apt-get install rails3`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what's the difference between the two?

Comment: With the command in your question, you're (probably) downloading precompiled binaries of Ruby and Rails from their servers, and may be a newer version than what's in your archives. With `apt-get` you're using the versions that were compiled for Ubuntu, and Ruby and Rails are managed by the package manager, so when you upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version (14.10, etc.), your Ruby and Rails installations will also be upgraded to the version in those archives. In addition, there may be Ubuntu-specific patches/mods in Ruby to make sure it integrates with everything else.